# Property 'error' does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<any, any> | { error: AxiosError<unknown, any>; }'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm starting to use typescript and I don't understand why there are some issues with this code

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from 'axios';

const get = async () => {
    const url = 'https://example.com';
    const request: AxiosResponse | { error: AxiosError }  = await axios.get(url).catch((error: AxiosError) => ({ error }));

    if (request.error) {
        console.log(request.error)
    }

    console.log(request.data)
}
```

There are some errors, when I want to access `request.error` or `request.data`.

> Property 'error' does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<any, any> | {
> error: AxiosError<unknown, any>; }'.   Property 'error' does not exist
> on type 'AxiosResponse<any, any>'.ts(2339)
>
> Property 'data' does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<any, any> | {
> error: AxiosError<unknown, any>; }'.   Property 'data' does not exist
> on type '{ error: AxiosError<unknown, any>; }'.ts(2339)

Also, I don't want to use `try/catch`, I want to mate it work with inline `catch()` just like I did in javascript before.

@edit
I've managed to "solve it" like this

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from 'axios';

const get = async () => {
    const url = 'https://example.com';
    const request: AxiosResponse | { error: AxiosError, [key: string]: any  }  = await axios.get(url).catch((error: AxiosError) => ({ error }));

    if ("error" in request) {
        console.log(request.error)
    }

    console.log(request.data)
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to use `request.error` instead of `"error" in request`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly type your `request` (which would probably be better named `response`). Axios (just like many other TS packages) already contains the return type.

If you really need to do this inline `catch`, the better approach is to create a [Type Guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). So it would be something like that

```
import axios, { AxiosError } from 'axios'

const get = async () => {
  const url = 'https://example.com'
  const response = await axios
    .get(url)
    .catch((error: AxiosError) => ({ error }))

  if (isErrorObject(response)) {
    console.log(response.error)
  } else {
    console.log(response.data)
  }
}

const isErrorObject = (obj: unknown): obj is { error: AxiosError } => {
  return (obj as { error: AxiosError }).error !== undefined
}
```

But, honestly, unless you really need this approach, I would recommend something much simpler:

```
const get = async () => {
  const url = 'https://example.com'
  axios
    .get(url)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```